# fetch a specififc whole array element from a string array based on a matching string using java

Tags: java

I know how to fetch an element from a string array .. but I have some different requirement here :

I have a string array

```
String[] = [Kausiote 1 (5)
, 17.10.2017
, Nordea Capital Private
, no. 006010512
, Kausi 01.01.2016 - 31.12.2016
, KAUSTISIS PIVKKU
, *1562
, PITTISAAVISTII 1A G 15
, 20100 TURKU
, Kausiote
, Omistaja: KAUSTISIS PIVKKU MAVKA KAAVISA
, Henkilötunnus: 291141-012J
, Sopimusaika
, 17.11.2010 - 16.11.2040
, Kausiote 2 (5)
, 17.10.2017
, Nordea Capital Private
, no. 006010512
, Kausi 01.01.2016 - 31.12.2016
, Sijoitussuunnitelma
, Sopimukseen liittyy Nordea Private Bankingin allokaatiopalvelu, jonka profiiliksi on valittu:
, Maltillinen
, BGF European A2 0,90 %
, BGF US Small and Mid Cap Opportuniti 0,50 %
, Fidelity America 1,00 %
, Fidelity Pacific Kasvu 1,70 %
, JP Morgan Europe Select Equity 0,50 %
, Nordea 1 Flexible Fixed Income Fund 23,21 %
, Nordea 1 US Corporate Bond BP 2,00 %
, Nordea Corporate Bond I 8,80 %
, Nordea PB Fixed Income Credit Opport 24,15 %
, Nordea Private Banking Equity Core C 8,00 %
, Nordea Private Banking Equity Opport 7,80 %
, Nordea Pro Euro Obligaatio 16,64 %
, Nordea Pro Suomi 3,80 %
, Wellington US Research Equity Fund 1,00 %
, Yhteenveto vakuutussäästöistä
, Säästöt 31.12.2015 631 758,82
, Maksetut maksut
, 16.08.2016 15 000,00
, Veloitukset
, Hoitopalkkiot säästöistä -952,92
, Yhteensä -952,92
, Arvonmuutos 40 312,32
, Säästöt 31.12.2016 686 118,22
, Säästöille kertynyt vuosituotto 6,2 %
, Kausiote 3 (5)
, 17.10.2017
, Nordea Capital Private
, no. 006010512
, Kausi 01.01.2016 - 31.12.2016
, Vakuutuksen kuluprosentti on 0,1 %. Kuluprosentin laskennassa on huomioitu vakuutuksesta perityt
, kulut ja verrattu niitä kauden alun säästöihin ja kauden aikana maksettuihin maksuihin.
, Kuluprosentissa ei ole huomioitu sijoituskohteiden kuluja, jotka on esitetty alla.
, Säästöjen jakautuminen 31.12.2016
, Määrä Kurssi Säästöt Osuus Kulu
, kpl euro euro % %
, Nordea Corporate Bond I 23 737,28550 2,22255 52 757,30 7,69 0,40
, Nordea Pro Euro Obligaatio 5 374,73912 24,08515 129 451,40 18,87 0,30
, BGF European A2 49,54809 105,97000 5 250,61 0,77 1,50
, BGF US Small and Mid 27,93463 184,80000 5 162,32 0,75 1,50
, Cap Opportunities
, Fidelity Pacific Kasvu 707,85426 19,04000 13 477,55 1,96 1,50
, Vakuutustili 16,71673 1 007,25948 16 838,08 2,45 *
, Nordea 1 US Corporate 1 063,17756 12,93000 13 746,89 2,00 0,70
, Bond BP
, Nordea 1 Flexible Fixed 1 105,27543 107,09000 118 363,95 17,25 0,55
, Income Fund BI
, Fidelity America 535,39181 25,82000 13 823,82 2,01 1,89
, JP Morgan Europe Select 2,77436 1 266,32000 3 513,23 0,51 1,92
, Equity
, Nordea Finland C 16 962,63722 2,20421 37 389,21 5,45 0,75
, Nordea PB Fixed Income 15 845,80169 10,24961 162 413,29 23,67 0,75
, Credit Opportun
, Nordea Private Banking 4 662,15545 10,09479 47 063,48 6,86 1,59
, Equity Opportun
, Nordea Private Banking 6 245,77030 10,70598 66 867,09 9,75 1,05
, Equity Core C
, Yhteensä 686 118,22 100,00 0,73
, * Sijoituskohteen kulua ei voi esittää.
, Kausiote 4 (5)
, 17.10.2017
, Nordea Capital Private
, no. 006010512
, Kausi 01.01.2016 - 31.12.2016
, YHTEENVETO SOPIMUKSEN SÄÄSTÖISTÄ KOKO SOPIMUSAJALTA
, Maksetut maksut yhteensä koko sopimusajalta 592 000,00 euroa
, Säästöjen nettotuotto 98 704,53 euroa
, Vuosituotto 2,5 %
, Nordea Asiakaspalvelu, puh. 0200 3000 (pvm/mpm) ma-su 24 h/vrk
, Kausiote 5 (5)
, 17.10.2017
, Nordea Capital Private
, no. 006010512
, Kausi 01.01.2016 - 31.12.2016
, Selvitys sopimuksesta perittyjen kulujen perusteista
, Hoitopalkkiot
, Sijoitussidonnaisista säästöistä veloitetaan tällä hetkellä 0,40 % vuotuista hoitopalkkiota
, 100 000 euroon asti, sen ylittävästä osasta vuotuisen hoitopalkkion määrä on 0,10 %.
, Takuusäästöistä veloitetaan tällä hetkellä vuotuista hoitopalkkiota 0,40 %.
, Sijoituskorien hallinnointipalkkiot
, Sijoituskorien hallinnointipalkkio on vähennetty niiden päivittäisestä arvosta.
, Vakuutusyhtiöllä on oikeus nostaa sijoituskorien vuotuista hallinnointipalkkiota korien
, sääntöjen mukaisesti.
, Sijoituskohteiden kulut
, Sijoituskohteiden palkkiot on vähennetty niiden päivittäisestä arvosta.]
```

So from above array I wants to get whole element if that element contains a matching string like :

I wants to fetch this array element as whole `", Henkilötunnus: 291141-012J"`.. if and only if it contains `"291141-012J"`. OR I wants to check each element in this array if a element contains "291141-012J".. if yes.. then fetch that whole element.

Please provide some solutions for this.

I have tried following

```
 public string getval(String[] atrArray, String attrName){

    for(String str ; atrArray){
    if(str.contains("291141-012J")){
    system.out.println(str);
//here I get my required element.  but how to rerun the same ..please suggest
    break
          }
      }
    }
```

Here i wants to return str .. how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a place to simply ask for solutions. You need to show us what you have tried. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to meet these guidelines.

Comment: did you heard of `String.contains("291141-012J")` method ? Any way you string array is wrong

Comment: I have tried following :

Comment: public string getval(String[] atrArray, String attrName){

for(String str ; atrArray){
if(str.contains("291141-012J")){
break
}
}
}

Here i wants to return str .. how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **return** statement as in:

```
return myString;
```

But you need to keep in mind that you also want to return any element that would contain the string value of **"291141-012J"** so your method could very well return 1 OR more elements. For this reason you may want to consider returning a String Array or an ArrayList. You could do it as a delimited string but I think it's just nicer if an Array is returned.

**Returning a String:**

```
public String getVal(String[] atrArray, String attrName){
    // Return a Null string ("") if the supplied Array
    // contains nothing or the attrName parameter 
    // contains Null or Null String.
    if (atrArray.length == 0 || attrName == null || attrName.isEmpty()) { 
        return ""; 
    }
    String returnString = ""; 
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < atrArray.length; i++) {
        str = atrArray[i]; 
        if(str.contains(attrName)){
            if (returnString.equals("")) {
                returnString+= str;
            }
            else {
                // Delimit any addition elements with
                // a semicolon.
                returnString+= ";" + str;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

To use the above method:

```
String[] atrArray = {"This", "is", "my", "array"}; // 4 elements
String result = getVal(atrArray, "i");
System.out.println(result);
```

The console output would display:

```
This;is
```

If however you want to return everything found within a String Array that matches the string placed into the **attrName** parameter then your method may look like this:

**Returning a Single Dimensional String Array:**

```
public String[] getVal(String[] atrArray, String attrName){
    // Return Null if the supplied Array contains 
    // nothing or the attrName parameter contains 
    // Null or Null String.
    if (atrArray.length == 0 || attrName == null || attrName.isEmpty()) { 
        return null; 
    }

    String[] returnArray = {};
    String wrkString = ""; 
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < atrArray.length; i++) {
        str = atrArray[i]; 
        if(str.contains(attrName)){
            if (wrkString.equals("")) {
                wrkString+= str;
            }
            else {
                // Delimit any additional elements with
                // something obscure like the Pipe (|) 
                // character since some elements might
                // contain data utilizing the usual
                // delimiters used.
                wrkString+= "|" + str;
            }
        }
    }
    // Now use the String.split() method to convert 
    // our Pipe delimited string to a String Array.
    if (!wrkString.equals("")) {
        returnArray = wrkString.split("\\|");
    }
    // Return our String Array
    return returnArray;
}
```

To use the above method:

```
String[] atrArray = {"This", "is", "my", "array"}; // 4 elements
String[] result = getVal(atrArray, "i");

// Display the results found:
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Item " + (i + 1) + " found at atrArray Index: " 
                     + i + " --> " + res[i]);
}
```

The console output would display:

```
Item 1 found at atrArray Index: 0 --> This
Item 2 found at atrArray Index: 1 --> is
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for this.. I have tried and it is working in my case.